# how solve that exception in java creating bar chart?

Tags: java, netbeans, jfreechart

i added three library:1-jfreechart-1.0.14-swt  2-jfreechart-1.0.14  3-jcommon-1.0.17

with this code:

```
private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset=new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    dataset.setValue(80,"Marks","student1");
    dataset.setValue(70,"Marks","student2");
    dataset.setValue(60,"Marks","student3");
    dataset.setValue(50,"Marks","student4");

    JFreeChart chart=ChartFactory.createBarChart("student score","student name","marks",dataset,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,false,true,false);
    CategoryPlot p=chart.getCategoryPlot();
    p.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.BLACK);

    ChartFrame frame=new ChartFrame("bar chart for student",chart);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(450,350);
}
```

thats Exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jfree/util/PublicCloneable
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Comment: Try updating the JCommon library and making sure it's in your classpath.

Comment: i updated to jcommon-1.0.23 and jfreechart-1.0.19  but still i have same Exception :( please help me @MasterOdin

Comment: Try `java -cp .:lib/* org.jfree.chart.demo.BarChartDemo1`.

Comment: i have same Exception.. not showed BarChart :(  @CatalinaIsland